# Como pegar a cor de destaque do Windows?

Tags: c#, xaml

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Como eu acesso a cor de destaque do Windows 10 definida pelo usuário.

Comment: Poderia especificar melhor `cor de destaque`? Talvez com uma imagem.

Comment: Para quem votou em fechar, qual o problema com a pergunta? Acho ela totalmente válida.

Comment: vi recentemente uma pergunta parecida e na resposta enviaram esse link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors(v=vs.110).aspx pelo que foi dito na pergunta, essa classe é própria para isso. se você tiver usando WPF também. Boa sorte.

Comment: Vê se isso aqui resolve, olhei em um fórum. var color = (Color)this.Resources["SystemAccentColor"];

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um teste numa app com o .net core 3.1.

Primeiramente você precisa instalar a lib `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` via NuGet.

Feito isso, você pode utilizar da seguinte forma:

```cs
var uiSettings = new UISettings();

// Carrega a cor
Windows.UI.Color accentColor = uiSettings.GetColorValue(UIColorType.Accent);

// Converte para o objeto Color
Color color = Color.FromArgb(accentColor.A, accentColor.R, accentColor.G, accentColor.B);

this.BackColor = color;
```

Testei no Windows 11 e funciona, acredito que deva funcionar também no Windows 10.